# Oracle SQL - Generate and update a column with different random number in every row

Tags: sql, oracle, random, oracle10g

Need help with SQL - I want to generate and update a column in every row with a different random number.

Database # Oracle 10g.

Example - When I do something like this it updates all the rows with the same number

```
update mytable r 
set r.generated_num = 
(select floor(dbms_random.value(100,9999999)) from dual).
```

Any advice?

Comment: a couple of questions: why does it need to be random? does it need to be unique within the table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like sub-query is the problem.

This seems to be working-

```
update mytable r set r.generated_num = TRUNC(dbms_random.value(1,9999999))
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity, and posting back what you have figured out. This doesn't necessarily ensure each row will get a different value though, if that is truly a concern

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a distinct random number, well, you're going to have to generate many, many more numbers than rows.

Note the following query:

```
with generator as
(select /*+ materialize */ rownum rn from dba_objects where rownum <= 250)
select count(distinct rv), count(rv) from
(
select trunc(dbms_random.value(1,9999999)) as rv
  from generator v1
       cross join generator v2
       cross join generator v3
 where rownum <= 10000000
)
```

Some example executions:

```
COUNT(DISTINCTRV)  COUNT(RV)
----------------- ----------
          6321429   10000000
          6321827   10000000
          6321941   10000000
          6321507   10000000
```