# How to update random oracle another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have table `contacts`

```
ID       CONTACT_ID      TYPE_ID
1            5               1
2            8               1
3            9               1                        
4            12              2        
5            13              1        
6            17              2                          
7            22              2                        
8            23              2    
9            25              1      
10           33              2                   
11           34              2                       
12           48              1      
.            ...             ...    
n            n               2
```

how can I update contact_id random, but not change type_id(where type_id = 1 random update this contacts or where type_id = 2->update random this contacts)
for example

```
ID       CONTACT_ID      TYPE_ID
    1            9               1
    2            13              1
    3            8               1                        
    4            17              2        
    5             5              1        
    6            22              2                          
    7            12              2                        
    8            33              2    
    9            48              1      
    10           34              2                   
    11           23              2                       
    12           25              1      
    .            ...             ...    
    n            n               2
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  Desired results can help in such cases.

Comment: Do you want to write a program that could do so, or just want a query?

Comment: I need only query

Comment: Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750573/oracle-sql-generate-and-update-a-column-with-different-random-number-in-every

Comment: I want to update random, but existing values, and not generate new contact_id

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, though a little misleading question. This `merge` worked for me:

```
merge into contacts c
using (
    with t as (
        select c.*, 
               row_number() over (partition by type_id order by id) rn1,
               row_number() over (partition by type_id order by dbms_random.value) rn2 
          from contacts c)
    select t1.id, t1.type_id, t1.contact_id, 
           (select contact_id 
              from t t2 where type_id = t1.type_id and rn1 = t1.rn2) as contact_new
      from t t1) s
on (c.id = s.id)
when matched then update set contact_id = s.contact_new;
```

At first I generated numbers partitioned by `type_id` and ordered by `id` (`rn1`) and randomly (`rn2`). You can see it running inner query separately. In the next step I used this query in `merge` as source data.